# What are the usages of the modifier "Many"?

Tags: meaning, grammar

> **Many** of his books are...
>
> His **many** books are...
>
> **Many** books of him/himself/John/Alex/etc...

Would you kindly tell me the exact difference between these?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Usage of "many" vs "many a"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/25555/usage-of-many-vs-many-a)

Comment: Your third example has the wrong form. It should be *"many books of **his**"*, *"many books of **John's***", and so forth. It means the same thing as the first one, but would be used much less frequently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I can explain the difference in the sentences by telling you that not all of the sentences are correct.

The first sentence is correct:

Many of his books are fantasy novels/crime novels. 
Many of his priceless books were destroyed in the fire.
I enjoyed reading many of his books.

The second sentence *His many books . . .* is a formal style of English, but most people don't speak or write like this. Most people write and say: *Many of his ***_****.

*Many of his books . . .* as you wrote in the first sentence.

The third sentence is also grammatically false and would not be spoken or written by a native-English speaker. This is not English sentence structure. Again, the correct way to express this thought is:

*Many of his books/John's books/her books* were stolen during the burglary.

In English, you can never say *Many books of himself*. The most common way to say this is expressed in your first sentence, *Many of his books . . .*

To avoid grammatical or structural mistakes, it's best to use basic language or language that is in common use.

Comment: Actually, the second sentence is merely florid, not ungrammatical. Compare _Her many accomplishments merit high praise_. This construction (there are many, many constructions with _many_) presupposes that she has many accomplishments, and asserts that they merit high praise. _Many of her accomplishments merit high praise_ says something rather different, and much less fulsome.

Comment: @John Lawler.  I did hesitate saying _His many books . . ._ was not correct English. As a long-time EFL instructor abroad, I've learned to simply explanations so as to not overwhelm low-level learners. You'll agree, though, that it's not common usage and it's unlikely that any non-native learner of English will be speaking or writing at this level of the language.  I'll edit it to that effect.

Comment: @Babs: Yeah, that's what I meant by 'florid'. Suitable for introductions of distinguished speakers by local custardheads, and the like. I started off my career with EFL, too (back when everybody called it "EFL", in fact).

Comment: @Babs: In light of your edit, I've cancelled my downvote and deleted the first comment. But I will just say that I don't think ELU is the right site for a non-native learner of English to be asking this type of question. By implication, the *answers* here should not be pitched at that level (but your approach would certainly be more than welcome on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/), so I do urge you to check that out).