# Is "many a person" singular or plural?

Tags: grammaticality, grammatical-number, verb-agreement, determiners

I'm writing a paper and I am not sure how to word this sentence. Which is the correct sentence:

1. > I am able to avoid a pitfall into which many a student **has** fallen.
2. > I am able to avoid a pitfall into which many a student **have** fallen.

I think the correct one is the first one since *has* agrees with *student*, but both sort of 'sound right' to me. Maybe because *have* agrees with *many*, you know? Can anyone tell me which is the correct wording?

Comment: The question here and the other one there do not ask the same thing. Here, the question is about subject-verb agreement with the construct "many a + singular noun"; there, the question is about the context in which "many a" can be used.

Comment: @asef: [the answers there](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/116670/300) do answer this question here, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first is correct:

1. > I am able to avoid a pitfall into which many *a student* **has** fallen.

The second could be modified to take a plural noun and still retain an equivalent meaning:

2. > I am able to avoid a pitfall into which many *students* **have** fallen.

I believe the choice is just down to preference.